# Populate multiselect options onchange of dropdown using AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have created a content type (Geological Locations) with 2 fields, Country and States.

The Country field is a select box, and States field is a multiselect. So if i select a Country, the States multiselect should be populated based on the selected Country using AJAX.

In my custom module, i used **node_form_alter()** to customize the node creation form.

I have tried the below code, but it is not working as expected.

```
function demo_form_geological_locations_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false;
    $form['field_country']['und']['#options'] = array(''=>'Select', 'india'=>'India', 'usa'=>'USA');
    $selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_country']) ? $form_state['values']['field_country'] : '';

    $form['field_country']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
          'callback' => 'ajax_states_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'states-wrapper',
    );

    $form['field_states']['#prefix'] = '<div id="states-wrapper">';
    $form['field_states']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['field_states']['und']['#options'] = ajax_get_state_options($selected);

    return $form;
}

function ajax_states_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['field_states'];
}

function ajax_get_state_options($key = '') {
    $options = array(
        t('usa') => drupal_map_assoc(
          array(
            t('Florida'),
            t('Georgia'),
            t('Atlanta')
          )
        ),
        t('india') => drupal_map_assoc(
          array(
            t('Maharashtra'),
            t('Gujarat'),
            t('Karnataka')
          )
        )
    );

    if (isset($options[$key])) {
        return $options[$key];
    }
    else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?
I am expecting the output like below screenshot, when i select the Country "India":

[image]

Comment: Have you considered an alternative method: Create your geo information as parent/child terms in a vocabulary, then use hierarchical select module in multi select mode.

Comment: Actually the data of Countries and States comes from an external API (hundreds of records) and i parse it to create custom arrays, so that i can use AJAX to populate States field, based on the selected Country.

Comment: Not sure if my code is not working, because i am using form_alter().

Comment: As an update, the solution by Naveen Valecha worked out well. And I have shifted to the Dev version of the multiselect module, as the original version is giving some warnings with AJAX onchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome question with full detail.After checking I tested it on my local dev box for its fix.
Use the below code for its fix. I have written the problem & its fix below.

```
    <?php

function demo_form_geological_locations_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['additional_settings']['#access'] = false;
  $form['field_country']['und']['#options'] = array(''=>'Select', 'india'=>'India', 'usa'=>'USA');
  $selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_country']) ? $form_state['values']['field_country']['und'][0]['value'] : '';
  $form['field_country']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_states_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'states-wrapper',
  );
  $form['field_states']['#prefix'] = '<div id="states-wrapper">';
  $form['field_states']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  $form['field_states']['und']['#options'] = ajax_get_state_options($selected);
  return $form;
}

function ajax_states_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_states'];
}

function ajax_get_state_options($key = '') {
    $options = array(
        t('usa') => drupal_map_assoc(
          array(
            t('Florida'),
            t('Georgia'),
            t('Atlanta')
          )
        ),
        t('india') => drupal_map_assoc(
          array(
            t('Maharashtra'),
            t('Gujarat'),
            t('Karnataka')
          )
        )
    );

    if (isset($options[$key])) {
        return $options[$key];
    }
    else {
        return array();
    }
}

?>
```

Problem was at line

```
$selected = isset($form_state['values']['field_country']) ? $form_state['values']['field_country'] : '';
```

you were passing the array to the selected value .i.e. countries array but the function ajax_get_state_options needs the key of selected country to return the array of states based on selected country.

I have tested this on php 5.3.27
Other suggestions :

1. you can also use the existing field api wrapper generated by field api.

P.S. : Double slap myself to track this small mistake in 1h 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of the following modules?

[Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiselect) (this one suits the most)

[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) (relatively easy to configure)

[Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) (requires separate dropdown lists)

A combination of Multiselect and Hierarchical Select will mostly help you achieve what you have shown.

Regards,

Supriya Rajgopal

Comment: Can i use Hierarchical Select module with Form API to populate the Countries and States, using AJAX?

Comment: Yes shasi, I think you can use. Please read the README.txt in the module for more information.

Comment: Hierarchical select is broken in D7, maybe try [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You return `$form['field_states']` wrapped in `<div id="states-wrapper">` to replace content of `<div id="states-wrapper">`. Try removing wrapper when returning form element via AJAX like:

```
function ajax_states_callback($form, $form_state) {
    unset($form['field_states']['#prefix']);
    unset($form['field_states']['#suffix']);
    return $form['field_states'];
}
```

You should consider moving `$form['field_states']` to a container.

Comment: I tried removing wrapper while returning AJAX response, but it did not work. Can you clarify how to use a container for the field?

Comment: I meant, something like `$form['field_states_container'] = array('#type' => 'container', '#prefix' => '<div id="states-wrapper">', '#suffix' => '</div>', 'field_states' => $form['field_states']); unset($form['field_states']);`, however I'm not sure it won't break anything in further form processing, since it's not a custom field. Anyway you can try it to check whether it is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try  [Reference Field Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) 
Find the Documentation related to this module here [Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit)